# Selenium WebDriver findElement(By.xpath()) is not fully working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I had a problem trying to scrape some information from a website https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferta/idealna-inwestycja-super-komunikacja-ID4jIKa using XPath. While I managed to successfully retrieve some of the data using the same method, I couldn't retrieve the rest. I'm not sure what went wrong and would appreciate any advice or insights on how to tackle this issue. If anyone could help me pinpoint the issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

`

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Ustawienie ścieżki do pliku chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")

# adres strony z ogłoszeniami
#url = 'https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferta/apartament-warsaw-apartments-jerozolimskie-roi-14-ID4k8Cl'
#url = 'https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferta/bemowo-52-mkw-rozklad-2-pokoje-balkon-ID4kFl0'
url = 'https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferta/idealna-inwestycja-super-komunikacja-ID4jIKa'


xpath_list = ['//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/header/div[2]/a',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/header/strong',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[10]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div/p',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[9]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[10]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[11]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[12]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[8]/div[1]'
]


Wartości = ["Adres", "Cena", "Powierzchnia", 'Forma własności', 'Liczba pokoi', 'Stan_wykończenia', 'Piętro','Balkon/Ogród/Taras', 'Czynsz', 'Miejsce parkingowe',
'Ogrzewanie','opis', 'Rynek', 'Typ ogłoszeniodawcy','Dostępne od','Rok zabudowy','Rodzaj zabudowy','Okna', 'Winda', 'Media','Zabezpieczenia','Wyposazenie','Informacje dodatkowe','Materiał budynku','Nr oferty']

# otwieramy stronę z ogłoszeniem
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

accept_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
accept_button.click()


xpath_dict = {}
for index, xpath in enumerate(xpath_list):
    try:
        # znajdź element na stronie za pomocą XPath
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
        # dodaj element do słownika, przypisując wartość do odpowiedniego klucza ze słownika Charakterystyki
        xpath_dict[Wartości[index]] = element.text
    except:
        # w przypadku błędu zwróć wartość 0 i przejdź do następnego elementu
        xpath_dict[Wartości[index]] = "NaN"
        pass`
```

xpath_dict
Output:

{'Adres': 'Warszawa, Białołęka, ul. Talarowa',
'Cena': '357 750 zł',
'Powierzchnia': '28,62 m²',
'Forma własności': 'pełna własność',
'Liczba pokoi': '1',
'Stan_wykończenia': 'do zamieszkania',
'Piętro': '2/4',
'Balkon/Ogród/Taras': 'balkon',
'Czynsz': 'NaN',
'Miejsce parkingowe': 'NaN',
'Ogrzewanie': 'miejskie',
'opis': 'Zapraszam do zakupu mieszkania na zasadach praw cesji.\nMieszkanie znajduje się na warszawskim Tarchominie, gdzie znajdziemy wszystkie potrzebne do życia usługi od sklepów po szkoły.Blisko osiedla komunikacja miejska ( autobusy,tramwaje) którą szybko dojedziemy do metra i innych ważnych punktów na mapie Warszawy.\nOsiedle składa się z dwóch budynków o niskiej zabudowie, a pomiędzy nimi dużo zieleni czy stojaki na rowery.\nNa dachach budynków zainstalowane panele fotowoltaiczne które zmniejszą opłaty za oświetlenie części wspólnych.\nJest możliwość do kupienia miejsca w garażu w budynku obok.\nWizualizacje wnętrz przedstawiają możliwe wykończenie wnętrza przez firmę specjalizującą się w tym zakresie.',
'Rynek': 'NaN',
'Typ ogłoszeniodawcy': 'NaN',
'Dostępne od': 'NaN',
'Rok zabudowy': 'NaN',
'Rodzaj zabudowy': 'NaN',
'Okna': 'NaN',
'Winda': 'NaN',
'Media': 'NaN',
'Zabezpieczenia': 'NaN',
'Wyposazenie': 'NaN',
'Informacje dodatkowe': 'NaN',
'Materiał budynku': 'NaN',
'Nr oferty': 'Nr oferty w Otodom: 63805574'}

Answer (score 0):

These xpaths do not exist,

```
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div', 

'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[9]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[10]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[11]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[12]/div[2]/div'
```

and that is why you are getting None(as you've defined in the "except") for these.

Here is the working solution with correct xpaths:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Ustawienie ścieżki do pliku chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")

# adres strony z ogłoszeniami
#url = 'https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferta/apartament-warsaw-apartments-jerozolimskie-roi-14-ID4k8Cl'
#url = 'https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferta/bemowo-52-mkw-rozklad-2-pokoje-balkon-ID4kFl0'
url = 'https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferta/idealna-inwestycja-super-komunikacja-ID4jIKa'


xpath_list = ['//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/header/div[2]/a',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/header/strong',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[2]',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[10]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div/p',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[9]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[10]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[11]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[12]/div[2]/div',
'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[8]/div[1]'
]


Wartości = ["Adres", "Cena", "Powierzchnia", 'Forma własności', 'Liczba pokoi', 'Stan_wykończenia', 'Piętro','Balkon/Ogród/Taras', 'Czynsz', 'Miejsce parkingowe',
'Ogrzewanie','opis', 'Rynek', 'Typ ogłoszeniodawcy','Dostępne od','Rok zabudowy','Rodzaj zabudowy','Okna', 'Winda', 'Media','Zabezpieczenia','Wyposazenie','Informacje dodatkowe','Materiał budynku','Nr oferty']

# otwieramy stronę z ogłoszeniem
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

accept_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
accept_button.click()


xpath_dict = {}
for index, xpath in enumerate(xpath_list):
    try:
        # znajdź element na stronie za pomocą XPath
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
        # dodaj element do słownika, przypisując wartość do odpowiedniego klucza ze słownika Charakterystyki
        xpath_dict[Wartości[index]] = element.text
    except:
        # w przypadku błędu zwróć wartość 0 i przejdź do następnego elementu
        xpath_dict[Wartości[index]] = "NaN"
        pass

print(xpath_dict)
```

output:

```
{'Adres': 'Warszawa, Białołęka, ul. Talarowa', 'Cena': '357 750 zł', 'Powierzchnia': '28,62 m²', 'Forma własności': 'pełna własność', 'Liczba pokoi': '1', 'Stan_wykończenia': 'do zamieszkania', 'Piętro': '2/4', 'Balkon/Ogród/Taras': 'balkon', 'Czynsz': 'Zapytaj', 'Miejsce parkingowe': 'garaż/miejsce parkingowe', 'Ogrzewanie': 'miejskie', 'opis': 'Zapraszam do zakupu mieszkania na zasadach praw cesji.\nMieszkanie znajduje się na warszawskim Tarchominie, gdzie znajdziemy wszystkie potrzebne do życia usługi od sklepów po szkoły.Blisko osiedla komunikacja miejska ( autobusy,tramwaje) którą szybko dojedziemy do metra i innych ważnych punktów na mapie Warszawy.\nOsiedle składa się z dwóch budynków o niskiej zabudowie, a pomiędzy nimi dużo zieleni czy stojaki na rowery.\nNa dachach budynków zainstalowane panele fotowoltaiczne które zmniejszą opłaty za oświetlenie części wspólnych.\nJest możliwość do kupienia miejsca w garażu w budynku obok.\nWizualizacje wnętrz przedstawiają możliwe wykończenie wnętrza przez firmę specjalizującą się w tym zakresie.', 'Rynek': 'wtórny', 'Typ ogłoszeniodawcy': 'biuro nieruchomości', 'Dostępne od': 'brak informacji', 'Rok zabudowy': '2022', 'Rodzaj zabudowy': 'blok', 'Okna': 'brak informacji', 'Winda': 'tak', 'Media': 'internet, telefon', 'Zabezpieczenia': 'drzwi / okna antywłamaniowe, domofon / wideofon, monitoring / ochrona', 'Wyposazenie': 'brak informacji', 'Informacje dodatkowe': 'brak informacji', 'Materiał budynku': 'brak informacji', 'Nr oferty': 'Nr oferty w Otodom: 63805574'}
```